# How do polarizers really work?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electric-fields, electric-current, polarization

I've been searching for an explanation of how light is polarised, and I came across [this short youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mB3_d6wiKfs), which seemed reasonable.

From my lecture notes (ICL), I have that:

> [image: polarizer notes 1]

Okay, that's nice, no contradictions with the youtube video so far. But then the notes go on to say that:

> The simplest linear polarizer are wire polarizers. Polarization in the direction of the wire drives
> currents which leads to attenuation, whilst polarization orthogonal to the wires is unaffected. Natural materials can behave in the same way, especially long-chain polymers, such as Polaroid(TM) film.

This is backed-up by an answer given to [this question from this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352066/a-few-questions-about-the-way-a-linear-polarizer-filters-light) by @Gilbert which in their answer mentions that:

> "For a wire-grid polarizer, the light polarized perpendicular to the wires will pass through. This counterintuitive result is because any electric field polarized parallel to the wires would excite currents in the wires, thereby reflecting/absorbing the light."

Also, on the [Polarizer Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer) under "Absorbative polarizers" section it is stated that:

> A Polaroid polarizing filter functions similarly on an atomic scale to the wire-grid polarizer. It was originally made of microscopic herapathite crystals. Its current H-sheet form is made from polyvinyl alcohol (PVA) plastic with an iodine doping. Stretching of the sheet during manufacture causes the PVA chains to align in one particular direction. Valence electrons from the iodine dopant are able to move linearly along the polymer chains, but not transverse to them. $\color{red}{\text{So incident light polarized parallel to the chains is absorbed by the sheet;}}$$\color{red}{\text{light polarized perpendicularly to the chains is transmitted.}}$ The durability and practicality of Polaroid makes it the most common type of polarizer in use, for example for sunglasses, photographic filters, and liquid crystal displays. It is also much cheaper than other types of polarizer.

Bearing all the above facts in mind, then, if only the orthogonal components of the E-field are transmitted then why does figure 4] c) not look like this:

[image: optics notes 2]

since the parallel (to $\theta_p$ direction) components of the E-field were attenuated away?

Comment: Suppose this is a wire-grid-type polarizer. Your lecture notes didn't say that $\theta_p$ is the direction of the wire. It defines it as the transmission axis. So we can infer that the wires are perpendicular to $\theta_p$.

Comment: @kaylimekay Thanks for your reply. I hope you are right, and the wires must be perpendicular to the direction of $\theta_p$. It would just be nice to have the lectures notes tell you that, instead of having to make inferences.

Comment: @kaylimekay is correct. But I don't understand your confusion.  All of the quotes you provide say that transmission occurs when the polarization is perpendicular to the wire (or polymer).

Comment: @garyp Not all of them, the youtube video does not and neither does figure 4. My confusion is because this is simply not being explained **properly** by the lecture notes and other sources.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't (and haven't) looked at the YouTube video.  I see your complaint to Fig. 4, but in fairness to that author he doesn't say anything about the mechanism, only that light is transmitted when polarized along the transmission axis.  What physical mechanism defines that axis is not stated.  I'm not trying to be snarky. One of the lessons that my students struggle with is reading: read what's actually written, not what you think is written.  I do know from bitter experience that it's hard to write unambiguous physics statements, and many bad examples exist. Fig 4 is not one of those.

Comment: Fig 4 covers cases where polarization is achieved by methods other than the wire grid or long chain polymer.  For example, polarization by birefringent crystals,  on reflection (partial polarization in this case), by Rayleigh scattering (partial), by Brewster's angle (can be partial or nearly complete), by MacNeille beamsplitter ...   The author has kept things general enough to apply to many mechanisms.

Comment: The YouTube video:  a mess.  His description of how the light passes is Just Plain Wrong, a fact that he admits in the comments.   He should redo the video.  He starts talking about circular polarization, but this has nothing to do with the mechanism he describes later.   And he's a photographer, not a physicist.   The Internet is *full* of incorrect physics, a lot of which are on sites intended to be tutorials for novices.  The novice has no way of filtering them out.